# Problem with evaluating a line integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the following integral using Green's theorem: $$\oint _C y^3 \, dx -x^3 \, dy$$ where $C$ is a circle with radius of 2.

Applying the theorem yields: $$\iint _R -3x^2 - 3y^2 \, dx\,dy$$ where $R$ is a circular area with radius of 2.

Now, I try to evaluate the double integral as follows:

$$-3 \iint _R \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) \, dx\,dy$$

The circle $R$ is defined by $x^2+y^2=r^2=4$, so I substitute this relationship:

$$-3 \iint _R \left( 4 \right) \,dx\,dy$$
$$-3 \cdot 4 \iint _R dx\,dy$$

I note that $\iint _R dx\,dy$ is simply the area of $R$, which is $\pi r^2 = 4\pi$. Hence, the entire integral has the value $-3 \cdot 4 \cdot 4\pi = -48\pi$.

However, evaluating the integral with the substitution $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ yields $-24\pi$, which is also what online calculators and the answer key say it should be.

What did I do wrong in my original approach? Note that I tried the question again with $r=3$ just to make sure I was off by a factor of 2, not a factor of $r=2$. Still wrong, by that factor of 2.

Comment: The region $R$ in your integral is $\{(x, y): x^2 + y^2 \le 4\}$, not the boundary

Comment: In other words: the integrand (4) in your second $dx\,dy$ integral is wrong. You may want to switch to polar coordinates properly.